# Explaining equation steps (multiple line \text)

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'm trying to explain my steps in an equation. The problem is that the text is longer than the line in the `\flalign*` environment, is there any way to make the text span over multiple lines while maintaining alignment?

Instead of just this:
[image]

I want it to look something like this:

[image]
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article,leqno]{memoir}
\pagestyle{title}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}
\usepackage{sistyle, amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
GKA(a,b)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-(ax_i+b))^2 &&\text{Anvend hjælpesætning b.}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\underbrace{(y_i-\bar{y})}_\text{s}-\underbrace{a(x_i-\bar{x})}_\text{t}+\underbrace{(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b)}_\text{u})^2&&\text{Anvend omskrivning 2.}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} 
\begin{pmatrix*}[l]
\vphantom{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}}\underbrace{(y_i-\bar{y})^2}_\text{$s^2$}+\underbrace{a^2(x_i-\bar{x})^2}_\text{$t^2$}+\underbrace{(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))^2}_\text{$u^2$}\\
\vphantom{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}}-\underbrace{2a(y_i-\bar{y})(x_i-\bar{x})}_\text{2st}+\underbrace{2(y_i-\bar{y})(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))}_\text{2su}\\
\vphantom{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}}-\underbrace{2a(x_i-\bar{x})(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))}_\text{2tu}
\end{pmatrix*}&&\text{Gang med $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}$ og brug hjælpesætning a.}\\ 
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2+\frac{1}{n}a^2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2+\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))^2&&\text{Brug at $V_1=$ gennemsnittet af $x_i$-erne}\\
&\quad-2a\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})+2(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})\\
&\quad-2a(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})\\
&=V_2+a^2V_1+\frac{1}{n}\cdot n(\bar{y}-a\bar{x}-b)^2-2Ca+0-0\\
&=V_1\cdot a^2-2Ca+V_2+(\bar{y}-a\bar{x}-b)^2\\
&=f(a)+g(a,b)
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use a `\parbox` inside of `\text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to placing the explanatory text that is supposed to be automatically wrapped in a `\parbox` of a suitably chosen width (in the code below, I've chosen 4.5cm) that sets its material in ragged-right mode (in order to avoid big interword gaps), you may also want to eliminate all unneeded `\text` directives as well as get rid of all but one of the `\limits` modifiers; in display-math mode, `\sum` and `\sum\limits` produce the exact same output. Separately, since `GKA` presumably doesn't represent the product of variables named `G`, `K`, and `A`, you should write that term as either `\mathit{GKA}` or `\mathrm{GKA}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article,leqno]{memoir}
\pagestyle{title}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}

\usepackage{sistyle, mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\newcommand\textbox[2]{\parbox{#1}{\raggedright #2}}
\newcommand\tallstrut{\vphantom{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}}} % tall typographic strut

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
\mathit{GKA}(a,b)
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-(ax_i+b))^2 
&&\text{Anvend hjælpesætning b.}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigl(\,
    {\underbrace{(y_i-\bar{y})}_{s}} 
   -{\underbrace{a(x_i-\bar{x})}_{t}} 
   +{\underbrace{(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b)}_{u}}\,\bigr)^2
&&\text{Anvend omskrivning 2.}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} 
\begin{pmatrix*}[l]
{\underbrace{(y_i-\bar{y})^2}_{s^2}}+
{\underbrace{a^2(x_i-\bar{x})^2}_{t^2}}+
{\underbrace{(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))^2}_{u^2}}\\
\tallstrut-{\underbrace{2a(y_i-\bar{y})(x_i-\bar{x})}_{2st}}
+{\underbrace{2(y_i-\bar{y})(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))}_{2su}}\\
\tallstrut-{\underbrace{2a(x_i-\bar{x})(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))}_{2tu}}
\end{pmatrix*}
&&\textbox{4.5cm}{Gang med $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ 
                  og brug hjælpesætning a.}\\ 
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2+
  \frac{1}{n}a^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2+
  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))^2
&&\textbox{4.5cm}{Brug at $V_1=$ gennemsnittet af $x_i$-erne}\\
&\quad-2a\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})
 +2(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})\\
&\quad-2a(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})\\
&=V_2+a^2V_1+\frac{1}{n} n(\bar{y}-a\bar{x}-b)^2-2Ca+0-0\\
&=V_1 a^2-2Ca+V_2+(\bar{y}-a\bar{x}-b)^2\\
&=f(a)+g(a,b)
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd also recommend `{\underbrace{<math>}_{...}}` with an additional pair of braces to make the whole thing an ordinary atom instead of a `\mathop`.

Comment: @egreg  - Many thanks for this suggestion; I've implemented it and uploaded a new screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it, with `\parbox`es, and text in footnote size. Il also reduced the size of the matrix, with the `medsize` environment from `nccmath`.

Note that if you load `mathtools`, you don't have to load `amsmath`, since this package does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage{sistyle, amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb, nccmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
  GKA(a,b)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-(ax_i+b))^2 & & & &\text{\footnotesize Anvend hjælpesætning b.} \\
  &=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\underbrace{(y_i-\bar{y})}_\text{s}-\underbrace{a(x_i-\bar{x})}_\text{t}+\underbrace{(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b)}_\text{u})^2 & & & &\text{\footnotesize Anvend omskrivning 2.} \\
  &=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}
  \mathrlap{\begin{medsize}\begin{pmatrix*}[l]
    \vphantom{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}}\underbrace{(y_i-\bar{y})^2}_{s^2}{} + a^2\underbrace{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}_{t^2} +\underbrace{(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))^2}_{u^2} \\
    \vphantom{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}}-\underbrace{2a(y_i-\bar{y})(x_i-\bar{x})}_{2st} + \underbrace{2(y_i-\bar{y})(\bar{y})-(a\bar{x}+b)}_{2su} \\
    \vphantom{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}}-\underbrace{2a(x_i-\bar{x})(\bar{y})-(a\bar{x}+b))}_{2tu}
    \end{pmatrix*}\end{medsize}} & & & & \parbox[t]{4cm}{\footnotesize Gang med $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}$ og brug hjælpesætning a.}\\
  & =\!\mathrlap{\begin{aligned}[t]\frac{1}{n} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2
    + \frac{1}{n}a^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2 + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))^2 & \\
    &-2a\cdot\smash{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})\\
    & + 2(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b)) \cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i-\bar{y}) -2a(\bar{y}-(a\bar{x}+b))\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})
    \end{aligned}}& & & & \parbox[t]{4cm}{\footnotesize Brug at $V_1=$ gennemsnittet af $x_i$-erne. \\ Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text}\\[-0.5ex]
  &=V_2+a^2V_1+\frac{1}{n}\cdot n(\bar{y}-a\bar{x}-b)^2-2Ca+0-0\\
  &=V_1\cdot a^2-2Ca+V_2+(\bar{y}-a\bar{x}-b)^2\\
  &=f(a)+g(a,b)
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it a good idea to have `\sum\limits` in text mode? Careful with Danish hyphenation patterns -- apparently, "te-xt" is OK... :-)

Comment: It was in the O.P.'s post. Furthermore, the nolimits versiontakes more horizontal space, in small \parbox. So I thought it would be wiser to leave it as is. However I agree this is debatable.